# Why is Shimon's name not mentioned?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, shevatim-12-tribes, parashat-vezot-habracha

Why in V'zos Brachah, is Shimon not mentioned?

Except for [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rashi_on_Deuteronomy.33.7.5?lang=he) that said he is included in Yehudah name because of the incident with Cozbi Bat Tzur.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Makan and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: When you say "except for Rashi...", do you mean that you want answers other than the one presented by Rashi?

Comment: Actually, Rashi includes Reuvain with Yehudah.

Comment: The relevant source is Deuteronomy 33 - http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0533.htm (Possibly should have been in the question)

Answer (score 1):

[Ibn Ezra on Devarim 33:6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Deuteronomy.33.6?lang=he) suggests (in addition to Rashi’s explanation quoted in the question) that Moshe was following Ya’akov’s example, who blessed neither Shim’on nor Levi at the end of Bereishit. (Levi nevertheless received a blessing from Moshe in the merit of Aharon.)

[Ramban on Devarim 33:6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ramban_on_Deuteronomy.33.6?lang=he) writes that given that Moshe wanted to bless Ephraim and Menashe separately, one of the other tribes had to be left out, to ensure a total of twelve. Shim’on was the one omitted, because it was a small tribe and did not receive an expansive blessing from Ya’akov.